# Scrapy scraping table with uneven rows

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape tables in the pages here http://www.abyznewslinks.com/allco.htm but i am at a dead end, and would like to ask more experienced ones how should the tables be scraped, this is the code i have managed to write https://pastebin.com/zZMfxSeR. I need to scrape these fields as columns in the output CSV - country_region,media_name,media_url,media_type,media_focus,language,media_format. Now i get all the elements in the columns listed in one cell seperated by comma not separated into row for each element which is my aim. Should I iterate by columns firstly or something else?

```
class AbyzrowbyrowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'abyziter'
allowed_domains = ['abyznewslinks.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.abyznewslinks.com/argen.htm']

def parse(self, response):
    table = response.xpath("(//div)[position()>5 and position()<last()]//table//tr")
    for row in table:
        item=AbyzItem()
        item['country']=response.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/table//td//font/text()[last()]").getall()
        item['continent']=response.xpath("/html/body/div[3]//a[2]/text()").getall()
        item['region']=response.xpath("/html/body/div[3]//a[3]/text()").getall()
        item['country_region'] = row.xpath("td[1]/font/text()").getall()
        item['media_url'] = row.xpath("td[2]/font/a/@href").getall()
        item['media_name'] = row.xpath("td[2]/font/a/text()").getall()
        item['media_type'] = row.xpath("td[3]//font/text()").getall()
        item['media_focus'] = row.xpath("td[4]//font/text()").getall()
        item['language'] = row.xpath("td[5]//font/text()").getall()
        item['media_format'] = row.xpath("td[6]//font/text()").getall()
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you could check values before assessment as following:

```py
country = response.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/table//td//font/text()[last()]").getall()
continent = response.xpath("/html/body/div[3]//a[2]/text()").getall()
region = response.xpath("/html/body/div[3]//a[3]/text()").getall()
country_region = row.xpath("td[1]/font/text()").getall()
media_url = row.xpath("td[2]/font/a/@href").getall()
media_name = row.xpath("td[2]/font/a/text()").getall()
media_type = row.xpath("td[3]//font/text()").getall()
media_focus = row.xpath("td[4]//font/text()").getall()
language = row.xpath("td[5]//font/text()").getall()
media_format = row.xpath("td[6]//font/text()").getall()
item['country'] = country if contrty else ''
item['continent'] = continent if continent else ''
item['region'] = region if region else ''
item['country_region'] = country_region if country_region else ''
item['media_url'] = media_url if media_url else ''
item['media_name'] = media_name if media_name else ''
item['media_type'] = media_type if media_type else ''
item['media_focus'] = media_focus if media_focus else ''
item['language'] = language if language else ''
item['media_format'] = media_format if media_format else ''
```